# Difference between b"0" and what comes out of /dev/zero

Tags: linux, python, framebuffer

In my research into a way to make my Linux framebuffer go completely black, I stumbled upon the following which I'm looking to get an explanation for:

- command line: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/fb0`results in a completely black framebuffer
- Python: `Path('/dev/fb0').write_bytes(FBSIZE * b"0")` results in a completely *grey* framebuffer

Playing with the b"0" I could make the framebuffer lighter or darker grey, but never completely black.

What is coming out of `/dev/zero` that is not the same as `b"0"` in Python?

(Just to be complete, I ended up using `setterm --clear all`, but this phenomenon keeps on bugging me.)

Any insight in this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `b'0'` is incorrect - this is the "*zero character*" - as in the number, or ASCII value `0x30` / `48`... hence the grey. What you actually want is the literal "*zero value*", often referred to as "*nul*", or ASCII value `0x00` / `0`.

To get this, try using the escape sequence `b'\0'` or `b'\x00'` instead.

What you are currently using can also be achieved using the escape sequence `b'\x30'`.

---

```
$ python3 -c 'from pathlib import Path; Path("test.bin").write_bytes(8 * b"0")'
$ hexdump -Cv < test.bin
00000000  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30                           |00000000|
00000008
```

```
$ python3 -c 'from pathlib import Path; Path("test.bin").write_bytes(8 * b"\x00")'
$ hexdump -Cv < test.bin
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                           |........|
00000008
```

```
$ python3 -c 'from pathlib import Path; Path("test.bin").write_bytes(b"Hello012")'
$ hexdump -Cv < test.bin
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 30 31 32                           |Hello012|
00000008
```

Comment: aaah, yes, of course! how silly of me. thanks a lot!

Comment: A correct answer, but *"numeric zero character"* seems unnecessarily verbose.  You can discuss the number zero or the character for zero, but  *"numeric zero character"*?  You have to apply English grammar rules to deduce that the salient attribute is `character` rather than `numeric`.  The `numeric` adjective seems superfluous to me.

Comment: @sawdust I tend to err on the side of verbosity in an attempt at clarity / being explicit... but I agree and have made the suggested change.